# Video as background does not change back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

So I set up a video so be background /overlay the background.When you first enter the site, and the yellow button changes the bg ,when you exit it, the video does not display any more. any idea why?

JSFiddle example here [jsfiddle.net/px60zngm](http://jsfiddle.net/px60zngm)

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var yellowclicks = 0;
 $('.x').hide();
 $('.yellow-text-bg').hide();
 $('.round-button-circle-x').hide();
    $('.round-button-circle').click(function(){
        $('.round-button').css('margin-top','5%');
        $('#logo').fadeOut(80);
  $('.hiderow').hide();
        $('.round-button-circle').hide();
        $('.yellow-text-bg').delay(80).fadeIn(500);
  $('.round-button-circle-x').delay(80).fadeIn(500);
  yellowclicks =+1;
  $('.intro').hide();
    });
 $('body').click(function(){
  $('.yellow-text-bg').fadeOut(400);
  $('#logo').delay(500).fadeIn(500);
        $('.round-button-circle').delay(500).fadeIn(500).css('margin-top','10%');
 });

});
```

Comment: Could you please reformulate your question? I think we are having a hard time helping you because we do not understand your question.

Comment: The video doesn't display because it is inside the `intro` div which you are hiding on click with `$('.intro').hide();`

Comment: @APAD1 I'm dumb, can't believe I missed that. Thanks!